# Assign *args while using **kwargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

I have a python function which looks like this:

```
def test(a, b, *args):
    print(a, b, args)
```

And I have a dictionary (kwargs) which has only a and b as items in it.
I would like to call test like this:

```
test(**kwargs)
```

and assign more values to **args**. How do I do it, and if I can't, What is the right way to do this?

Comment: How are you trying to assign more values to `args` and what's the issue in doing so?

Comment: I don't suspect that will work because kwargs have to come after args.

Comment: The function above works, yet If I add more values after **kwargs it will have syntax error, so I would like to know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your function to always accept an either positional or keyword arguments: `a` and `b`, and a list of *positional* arguments after that.

In Python it's a Syntax Error to provide a positional argument after a keyword argument.

Therefore, you cannot use `**kwargs` dictionary unpacking in your method call, if you also want to provide additional positional arguments.

What you can do, though, is either use positional arguments only - making sure that `a` and `b` are the first two elements in your list.

Or if you really wan't to use a dictionary, You'd have to directly get `a` and `b` values, pass it positionally as `a` and `b`, and then get remaining `items()` from your dictionary and call your function with it. This will lose the key values though.

Comment: I thought that works like that, but in my case I have about 10 arguments which I get as kwargs dictionary and I just want to forward them to test function. It is very troublesome to unpack them individually just to set each positional argument, isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: Your test function still requires `a` and `b` to be present as the first parameters. Theoretically you could just use `*.yourdict.values()`, but you have to mind the order in which the arguments get unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using just `*args` as argument.

**Ex:**

```
def test(*args):
    print(args)

test({"a": 1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":[1,2,3,45]})
```

**Output:**

```
({'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': [1, 2, 3, 45]},)
```

Comment: It will make test less indicative, so i prefer not to erase the parameters from it if I can help it